# Creating XML Tree from SQL

Tags: sql, xml, xslt, tree

I have SQL table which has following data

| path | Level 1 | Level 2 | Level 3 | Level 4 | LEAF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A-B-C | ---A---- | ---B--- | ---C--- | -------- | N |
| A-B-C-D | ---A---- | ---B--- | ---C--- | ----D--- | Y |
| A-B-E-F | ---A---- | ---B--- | ---E--- | ----F--- | Y |
| A-B-E-G | ---A---- | ---B--- | ---E--- | ----G--- | Y |

Now based on above data I want form xml tree hierarchy and save the data as .xml file
I am using SQL, SSIS and XSLT Template

Expected Output should be like

```
`<A>
 <B>
  <C>
   <D></D>
  </C>
  <E>
   <F></F>
   <G></G>
 </B>
</A>`
```

Could anyone help how I can achieve this?

I have tried with for xml path approach but I couldn't get it. Solution with xslt template will do

Comment: The input to XSLT is XML. If you have an XML input, add it to your question.

Comment: <Portfolios>
  <Portfolio>
    <Path_>A-B-C</Path_>
    <LEVEL1>A</LEVEL1>
    <LEVEL2>B</LEVEL2>
    <LEVEL3>C</LEVEL3>
    <LEAF_FLG>N</LEAF_FLG>
   
   </Portfolio>
  <Portfolio>
    <Path_>A-B-C-D</Path_>
    <LEVEL1>A</LEVEL1>
    <LEVEL2>B</LEVEL2>
    <LEVEL3>C</LEVEL3>
    <LEVEL4>D</LEVEL4>
    <LEAF_FLG>Y</LEAF_FLG>
   
  </Portfolio>
  <Portfolio>
    <Path_>A-B-E-F</Path_>
    <LEVEL1>A</LEVEL1>
    <LEVEL2>B</LEVEL2>
    <LEVEL3>E</LEVEL3>
    <LEVEL4>F</LEVEL4>
    <LEAF_FLG>Y</LEAF_FLG>
    
  </Portfolio>
</Portfolios> This would be xml input

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question instead. Also state which processor you will be using (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153).

Comment: See if one these helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30672395/3016153, https://stackoverflow.com/a/33387703/3016153.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MS Sql Server and starting with the table. You can not create xml tags from data with a FOR XML query. You can build xml-like strings with string aggregation, for example

```
select * into tbl
from (
values
 ('A' , 'B' , 'C', 'D')
,('A' , 'B' , 'C',null)
,('A' , 'B' , 'E', 'F')
,('A' , 'B' , 'E', 'G')
)t(l1,l2,l3,l4);

with t4 as(
  select l1,l2,l3, coalesce(string_agg('<' + l4 + '></' + l4 + '>',''),'') x
  from tbl 
  group by l1,l2,l3
), t3 as (
  select l1,l2, coalesce(string_agg('<' + l3 + '>' + x + '</' + l3 + '>',''),'') x
  from  t4 
  group by l1,l2
), t2 as (
  select l1, coalesce(string_agg('<' + l2 + '>' + x + '</' + l2 + '>',''),'') x
  from t3
  group by l1
)
select cast(string_agg('<' + l1 + '>' + x + '</' + l1 + '>','') as xml) res
from t2
```

Returns

```
 <A><B><C><D /></C><E><F /><G /></E></B></A>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using powershell you can query the database and put results into a database (see : [Use SqlDataAdapter and DataTable to get and update on SQL server with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47468238/use-sqldataadapter-and-datatable-to-get-and-update-on-sql-server-with-powershell?force_isolation=true)).  Then use the following PS script

```
using assembly System.Data
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$filename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'
$dt = [System.Data.DataTable]::new()

$dt.Columns.Add('path') | out-null
$dt.Columns.Add('Level 1') | out-null
$dt.Columns.Add('Level 2') | out-null
$dt.Columns.Add('Level 3') | out-null
$dt.Columns.Add('Level 4') | out-null
$dt.Columns.Add('LEAF') | out-null


$dt.Rows.Add(('A-B-C', '---A----', '---B---', '---C---', '--------', 'N')) | out-null
$dt.Rows.Add(('A-B-C', '---A----', '---B---', '---C---', '----D---', 'N')) | out-null
$dt.Rows.Add(('A-B-C', '---A----', '---B---', '---E---', '----F---', 'N')) | out-null
$dt.Rows.Add(('A-B-C', '---A----', '---B---', '---E---', '----G---', 'N')) | out-null

function Add-Nodes
{
   param([System.Data.Datarow[]]$dt, [int]$index, [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]$node)
   $colData = $dt | Group-Object $('Level ' + $index)
   foreach($key in $colData)
   {
      $tagName = $key.Name.Trim('-')
      if($tagName -ne '')
      {
         $newNode = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get($tagName))
         $node.Add($newNode)
         if($index -lt $dt.Coumns.Count)
         {
            $childTable = $key.Group | Select-Object $_
            Add-Nodes -dt $childTable -index ($index + 1) -node $newNode
         }
      }
   }
}

$root = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('root'))
$index = 1
$dataRows = $dt | Select-Object $_
Add-Nodes -dt $dt -index $index -node $root

$root.Save($filename)
```

Here is the results

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <A>
    <B>
      <C>
        <D />
      </C>
      <E>
        <F />
        <G />
      </E>
    </B>
  </A>
</root>
```